# How can I test for a data frame content?

Tags: r, testthat

I have a routine that returns a data frame. I want to check if its values are reasonable. Using `testthat` I have `expect_equal`, but I am not sure if it applies to data.frames. I tried to do this but it doesn't work

```
testthat::expect_equal(result$ORs[1,1:3], c(1.114308, 0.5406599, 2.296604), tolerance=1.0e-6)
```

This is the message I get

```
─────────────────────────────────────────────────
test-xxx.R:19: failure: basic functionality
result$ORs[1, 1:3] not equal to c(1.114308, 0.5406599, 2.296604).
Modes: list, numeric
names for target but not for current
Attributes: < Modes: list, NULL >
Attributes: < Lengths: 2, 0 >
Attributes: < names for target but not for current >
Attributes: < current is not list-like >
─────────────────────────────────────────────────

══ Results ══════════════════════════════════════
Duration: 0.1 s
```

Comment: Do you want to test the whole data frame or just specific rows? Or map a whole row to several values?

Comment: @NelsonGon Ideally and in this case, I want to check if every value is within a given tolerance. This is trivial for small data frames, but for larger ones I will use a subset or sum along the columns or rows to check the final value.

Comment: Not really sure but could you explain how it fails? Testing with the "lower level" `compare` and `all.equal` seems to work.

Comment: @NelsonGon Edited with the error

Answer (score 0):

If you merely test for a specific column's value (e.g. `df[1,1]`), then you can  `unname` and `unlist` the value:

```
expect_equal(unname(unlist(df[1,1])), "Value")
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `...$ORs[1, 1:3]` is another `data.frame` because you take a row with more than one column:

```r
# data example
ORs <- data.frame(1:3, 0:2, 2:4)

# show that it is a data.frame
str(ORs[1, 1:3])
#R> 'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
#R>  $ X1.3: int 1
#R>  $ X0.2: int 0
#R>  $ X2.4: int 2
```

Same thing happens with multiple rows with more than one column. A few options are:

1. To `dput` the result and use the output (after possibly changing the entries to the expected values). Then you are sure that you have the correct attributes:

```r
dput(ORs[1, 1:3])
#R> structure(list(X1.3 = 1L, X0.2 = 0L, X2.4 = 2L), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")

expect_equal(
  ORs[1, 1:3], 
  structure(list(X1.3 = 1L, X0.2 = 0L, X2.4 = 2L), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame"))

# you can disregard the whole structure part if you use check.attributes = FALSE
# That is just list(...) with the expected values
expect_equal(ORs[1, 1:3], list(1L, 0L, 2L), check.attributes = FALSE)
```

2. use `expect_known_value` to store a .RDS file with expected output to test against.
3. Like suggested by [anpami](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65189326/5861244), unlist the data and test. This will work well particularly if all the `data.frame` entries are of the same type in the columns you are looking at (here the first three):

```r
expect_equal(unlist(ORs[1, 1:3]), c(1L, 0L, 2L), 
             check.attributes = FALSE)
```

4. test each value separately. This does not seem like a nice option though:

```r
expect_equal(ORs[1, 1], 1L)
expect_equal(ORs[1, 2], 0L)
expect_equal(ORs[1, 3], 2L)
```

Note that `expect_equal` uses `all.equal` so it is matter of getting `all.equal` to pass.